# Can light be trapped and if so would it be stuck in time

Tags: quantum-field-theory, visible-light

If you can trap light in a box perfectly wouldn't it be like a lamp or phone if it's on for to long it will over heat or cach fire and if it was perfectly evan would the light be trapped in time till you broke one of the sides of the box because light can travel by years so would it just be stuck?

Answer (score 1):

First off, there are no perfect boxes. But even if there were, not only would it not "over heat and catch fire", it in fact *wouldn't heat up at all!* Because in order for light to heat something up, the energy in that light, and thus the light itself, has to be absorbed by the thing being heated, and that would mean there was less light left in the box, i.e. it would not be a perfect box any more. Also, for an imperfect - that is, real - box, it can only heat up by the amount of heat that is represented by the energy of the contained photons. If you have only a few Joules' worth in there, then it will only heat up by a tiny fraction of a degree unless the box is very lightweight.

The idea that "light is trapped in time" needs refinement. What it means more precisely is that "a photon's 'internal clock' is perpetually frozen" - no sort of internal change or evolution can ever occur within the photon other than its creation and destruction. This is why photons do not decay, and can reach our telescopes even after having been emitted from galaxies that are now tens of billions of light-years away, at the time of the first formation thereof.

(The most proper formulation is that the space-time "distance", which represents the amount of time experienced by something travelling a particular path in space-time, is zero when measuring along a photonic worldline. That is to say, photons travel on paths that, in some strange geometric sense, encompass a nontrivial number of points, and yet are only as long as a single point!)